# Find average of multiple images

Tags: python, algorithm, feature-extraction

I have extracted edges that are in form of shape in an object. The shapes extracted contained 80 shapes. How do I find the average of 80 similar shapes to form a new shape, which will serve as a pattern to use for matching using python.

Comment: Could you add an example? What do you mean by "average of shapes"? Do you mean polygons or arbitrary shapes? Please clarify.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak thanks for your response, I actually hand to find the average of the result of canny edge detection on a dataset of particular images which is in form of shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine multiple images i would propose doing the following:

1. Read the files with the [OpenCV packages for Python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)
2. Convert the images to Numpy-Arrays
3. Use arythmetic or geometric mean to get a combination of all images
4. Save the resulting image using OpenCV

This would result in the shapes that are present in all immages to be more pronounced.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to find the average of the image and set a certain threshold for the resulting average. Please could you provide the python code for achieving this? Thanks,-- wuerfelfreak

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing-service. Use the steps I provided to guide you along the way. For now thats all I can do. If you encounter a roadblock on the way, we will be happy to help you though. Also please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking the checkmark.